# How do you use golang's ProbablyPrime?

Tags: go, primes

My attempts always return false :(

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    i := new(big.Int)
    j := i.ProbablyPrime(2)
    fmt.Println(j)
}
```

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the method documentation:

> ProbablyPrime performs n Miller-Rabin tests to check whether x is
>   prime. If it returns true, x is prime with probability 1 - 1/4^n. If
>   it returns false, x is not prime.

n, the argument you pass to the method, is not the number you're trying to test for primality, but rather determines the accuracy with which the prime guess is made: the higher the value of n, the more accurate the guess will be, at the expense of additional computation.

If you want to test whether 2 is prime, you may do (http://play.golang.org/p/ZGx4XOd6WA):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    i := big.NewInt(2)
    isPrime := i.ProbablyPrime(1)
    fmt.Println(isPrime)
}
```

Comment: I think you want `n` to be much larger than 1?  For n=1 you would still miss 3/4 of non-primes.  (This affects only large number, small primes are special-cased in the algorithm.)  I would suggest to write `isPrime := i.ProbablyPrime(10)` or so.

Answer (score 4):

`x.ProbablyPrime(n)` checks whether `x` is prime, not `n`. `n` is a factor which indicates how hard `ProbablyPrime` will try to determine `x`'s primality. The higher `n` is, the longer `ProbablyPrime` will take, and the more likely it is to be correct. Specifically, from the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.ProbablyPrime):

> If it returns true, x is prime with probability 1 - 1/4^n

So what you want is instead:

```
x := big.NewInt(2)
fmt.Println(x.ProbablyPrime(4))
```

Run it [here](http://play.golang.org/p/vgG91Ulsit) on the Go Playground.

Comment: The statement "x is prime with probability 1 - 1/4^n" makes no sense to me.  Either x is prime, or it isn't, there is no randomness involved.  In contrast, the output of the algorithm is random, so a statement like "If x is not prime, [the function] returns false with probability at least 1 - 1/4^n" makes much more sense.

Comment: I disagree. The probability that x is prime, given that the function returns true, is 1 - 1/4^n. If all we know about the world is that `x.ProbablyPrime(n)` returned true, then we know that the probability that x is prime is 1 - 1/4^n. Of course we could learn more about x and become more certain of its primality, but given only the knowledge of the output of `x.ProbablyPrime(n)`, that's the best we can do.